# Question regarding renewal processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, renewal-processes

I'm quoting from page 261 of "Measure theory and probability theory" by Krishna and Soumendra.

Let $N(t)$ and $S(t)$ be the associated renewal process and renewal sequence, the book proves the following

\begin{gather*}
P (N (t) > k) ≤ C(t)\lambda^k  \ \ \ \forall t
\end{gather*}

where $C(t)$ is a positive constant depending on $t$ and $\lambda \in(0,1)$ not depending on $t$. The proof is quite short:

> \begin{gather*}
> P(N(t)<k)=P(S_k \leq t) \\
> =P(e^{-\theta S_k} \geq e^{-\theta k}) \ \ \ \text{for} \ \ \theta>0 \\
> \leq e^{\theta t}E(e^{-\theta S_k}) \ \ \ \ \text{by Markov's inequality} \\
> = e^{\theta t}E(e^{-\theta X_0})\left(e^{\theta t}E(e^{-\theta X_1})\right)^k
> \end{gather*}
> and as $\theta$ goes to infinity we get $E(e^{-\theta X_1}) \rightarrow P(X_1=0)$ that is less then 1 by hypothesis.

Then it says that from this follows that $P(N(t)=k)= O(\lambda^k)$, but for me it's not clear how to prove this implication. May you demystify it? Thanks.